# Can't handshake website when calling a site programmatically

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, openssl, wget

So let me explain:

I trying to crawl this website: https://www.diariooficial.feiradesantana.ba.gov.br

Via Browser i can access without any problem.

But using, wget, curl, python or any automatic way i get SSL connect errors:

curl:

```
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.diariooficial.feiradesantana.ba.gov.br:443
```

wget:

```
Resolving www.diariooficial.feiradesantana.ba.gov.br (www.diariooficial.feiradesantana.ba.gov.br)... 200.187.60.119
Connecting to  www.diariooficial.feiradesantana.ba.gov.br (www.diariooficial.feiradesantana.ba.gov.br)|200.187.60.119|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Python using `requests` lib:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.diariooficial.feiradesantana.ba.gov.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",),))
```

I take a look at: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.diariooficial.feiradesantana.ba.gov.br

But don't understand why i can't connect, is possible to get response or ignore this errors?

My python script:

```py
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.diariooficial.feiradesantana.ba.gov.br')
print(r.text)
```

Comment: The SSL/TLS implementation of the server is broken to a point where some clients can't communicate with it anymore, and others who still manage to connect get a completely insecure connection.

Comment: Right, is there a way to by-pass this? Is not fault in libraries them?

Comment: You could compile Python or an SSL proxy against an older OpenSSL version. You could also try a Selenium based attempt with a browser that works to crawl the page. None of these is secure.